# Monitoring for an application running in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring

I have an application running on kubernetes (It is a cluster running on cloud) and want to setup monitoring and logging for that application. There are various possibilities for the setup. What would be the best practices of doing that, like recommended method or industrial standard?

- A **prometheus monitoring setup inside kubernetes cluster**: prometheus-operator helm chart installed inside the cluster that can monitor the entire cluster, including the application.
- an **external prometheus + grafana setup** deployed with docker-compose.(But I doubt if the external setup can reach the k8s properly to scrape all the metrics)
- A **prometheus federation setup** where one external prometheus setup gets metrics from an internal prometheus setup of k8s.

Can anyone please help me with some suggestions regarding best practices?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how many clusters you have. If you have one cluster, the application you want to monitor on it will be the best choice option 1:

> - A  **prometheus monitoring setup inside kubernetes cluster**  : prometheus-operator helm chart installed inside the cluster that can monitor the entire cluster, including the application.

The advantages of such a solution include possibly simple and quick configuration, in addition, you have everything in one place (application and Prometheus) and you do not need a new cluster to monitor another. [Here](https://www.replex.io/blog/kubernetes-in-production-the-ultimate-guide-to-monitoring-resource-metrics-with-grafana) you can find example tutorial.

However, if you plan to expand to many clusters, or you already need to monitor many clusters, option 3 will be the best choice:

> - A  **prometheus federation setup**  where one external prometheus setup gets metrics from an internal prometheus setup of k8s.

Thanks to this solution, you will have all the metrics in one place, regardless of the [number of clusters](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/) you need to monitor:

> Commonly, it is used to either achieve scalable Prometheus monitoring setups or to pull related metrics from one service's Prometheus into another.

You can find example tutorials about [Prometheus federation in Kubernetes](https://medium.com/@jotak/prometheus-federation-in-kubernetes-4ce46bda834e) and [Monitoring multiple federated clusters with Prometheus - the secure way](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/prometheus-federation/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions! Also, I have a doubt. Is it a good practice to setup the monitoring stack in a cluster that is actually  being monitored? Wouldn't it be a problem during an outage at the infrastructure level of the cluster?

Comment: @AnjanaAK, If you have a failure at the cluster level and monitoring is inside it, everything will fail. This type of method is good for small (non-production) solutions where you have one cluster and you put monitoring to study the behaviour in the cluster and also the application. If you need to monitor the cluster for its proper operation, try the second method described by me.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. And why the method `external prometheus + grafana setup deployed with docker-compose` is not preferred?

Comment: In fact, you've already suggested an answer to this question yourself. :) It would be difficult to run this correctly. Additionally, if it is somewhere externally, you have to consider the security issue very carefully so that someone does not hack in.